# Kill connections to handle 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction?

Tags: python, mysql

I use MySQL.connector in Python to build a database. I've suddenly ran into this error message.

[image: Error]

I figure from other posts here that this has something to do with too many connections. If I run the code below, I'll get this in return.

```
pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`innodb_trx` ORDER BY `trx_started`', mydb)
```

[image]¨

I also tried to increase the number of connections to 500. But that didn't change anything.

```
cursor.execute("set global max_connections = 500")
mydb.commit()
```

Now I'm trying to figure out what this information tells me. Should I kill all connections, and start over? Can I kill connections from python? And how can I avoid this problem in the future?

Comment: You shouldn't need to kill connections to resolve lock timeouts. Just optimize locking queries so they run quickly, and commit transactions promptly.

Comment: Interesting - I will look into that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my issue.

```
cursor.execute("select concat('kill ',id,';') sleeping_connections FROM information_schema.processlist isp WHERE Command = 'Sleep' and time > 60")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
df_ = pd.DataFrame( [[ij for ij in i] for i in rows] )
df_.rename(columns={0: 'Sleeping Connections'}, inplace=True);

for i in df_['Sleeping Connections']:
    cursor.execute(str(i))
```